# Why we prepend \Slim before using Slim class?

Tags: php, prefix, slim

Once we have included SLIM PHP class using require function, why do we still instantiate Slim class with **\Slim** prefix.

```
<?php
    $app = new \Slim\Slim(); // Why \Slim before Slim();
    $app->get('/hello/:name', function ($name) {
       echo "Hello, $name";
    });
$app->run();
?>
```

Please help me understand the role of prefix "\Slim" here.

Comment: It's a global namespace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the `Slim` class is defined under the `\Slim` namespace; the canonical reference is needed regardless of whether you've `require()`'d the file or not.

To avoid longer class references in your code, you can do this:

```
use \Slim\Slim;

$app = new Slim();
```

Comment: Aah! I thought it had something related to path. Thanks a lot Jack :)